# Get distinct values from HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

I want to get only distinct values from `HashSet`, I have implemented `IEquatable`, `IEqualityComparer`, but still can't get distinct values.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HashSet<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>()
        {
            {new Item("item1")},
            {new Item("item2")},
            {new Item("item3")},
            {new Item("item1")}
        };

        foreach (var item in items.Distinct())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


class Item : IEquatable<Item>, IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Item(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public bool Equals(Item other)
    {
        return this.Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
item1
item2
item3
item1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` as a separate class and you need to provide the whole equality comparer during `HashSet<T>` construction:

```
var set = new HashSet<CustomClass>(new CustomClassEqualityComparer());
```

If you go with the equality comparer way, you aren't forced to implement `IEquatable<T>`:

```
public class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you can design many `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementations to cover many use cases that can define different uniqueness meanings to the same object (i.e. `Item`).

If you provide a good implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`, you won't need `Distinct` since a `HashSet<T>` is a *set* and this means that it's an unordered collection of unique elements, and the whole *set* will use your equality comparer to check if a given element is present in the *set* (thus, all elements are unique in the same *set*!).

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a single implementation which defines equality of your class, implementing `IEquatable<T>` (properly) is enough. You shouldn't implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` as well. The latter is meant to be, usually as in a separate class, when you want to provide multiple ways to define uniqueness between two elements of a type.

Other than that, Your method signature for `GetHashCode` is wrong. Currently, it defers to `object.Equals` instead of your custom implementation.

You need to add the `override` keyword to your `GetHashCode` implementation and remove the `Item obj` from the signature:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

And also override `object.Equals` as well to use your `Equals(item other)`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
    return Equals((Item) obj);
}
```

public override bool Equals(
You don't need to call `Distinct()` on a `HashSet<T>` as it by itself guarantees uniqueness in its internal collection, given that you provide a proper `IEquatable<T>` override or supply it with an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

[From the docs of `HashSet<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value:
>
> Type: System.Boolean true if the element is added to the
> HashSet object; false if the element is already present.

Comment: What about 'Equals(arg1, arg2),  do they need 'override' keyword?

Comment: @MatjažMav No. You shouldn't need `Equals(arg1, arg2)` at all. You're fine with only implementing `IEquatable<T>`, not need for `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: C# automatically added this two methods in my code.

Comment: Because you implemented `IEqualityComparer`. Remove that.

Comment: But, if you really need it spelled out, you are explaining nothing of the difference between `IEquatable` and `IEqualityComparer`, how each should be used, what the differences are between them, etc., because *that* is the real problem here.  You've put forth an (incomplete) solution and not explained at all what is really wrong or why the changes being made.

Comment: @Servy *That* is the real problem here according to you. The fact that implementing both these interfaces is redundant doesn't change the fact that the OP was implementing `GetHashCode` wrong. I explain that there is no need to do that. The OP clearly doesn't understand why after implementing both his solution still doesn't work, which I spell out clearly.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, implementing both interface is indeed inappropriate.  **You never said that in your answer**.  That's a major problem with it.  He was *not* implementing `GetHashCode` wrong.  He was implementing it the proper way *for an equality comparer*.  He failed to implement it at all for the equality of the object itself.  It's okay to implement *either* the objects ability to compare itself, or a separate equality comparer.  The OP's problem is that he did half of each, and all of neither.  The problem with your answer is that you've explained none of this.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I've stated that there's no need to do that in the bottom part of my answer, perhaps it wasn't clear enough to you. I've edited my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You stated that there was no need to call `Distinct`.  You stated nothing about it being improper for an object to implement both `IEquatable` and `IEqualityComparer`.  You've stated nothing about what each interface conceptually means, or how to use either, let alone both.  You've also provided only one out of several steps in the process of converting that object to properly implementing the `IEquatable` pattern.

Comment: @Servy Not true. I've stated that there is no need to implement both. I did not state what each interface conceptually means as I didn't think that was relevant to my answer. I did not provide "only one step out of several", as the OP had already implemented `Equals(Item other)` properly. The only other thing perhaps worth mentioning is to override `Equals(object)`.

Comment: @Servy Anyway, I need to repeat myself (!DRY), and state again **time heals all wounds"**. After all, a downvote should not `happiness.Dispose()`. (this sounds very very geek uhmmm)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You claim that you didn't miss a step, and yet the OP has gone and posted comments about their code not working because of the steps that you've missed.  In this case, you're suggesting changing a working implementation of `IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode` to an object override, and in doing so the code won't compile as it won't implement that interface.  It'd also mean leaving the unused `Equals` method and having an interface implementation that doesn't belong.

Comment: @Servy I suggested dropping `IEqualityComparer` all around, not leaving it hanging. I didn't even regard that implementation as it should be completely removed in this particular case.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You mean you edited it in a few minutes ago, after I told you it was missing.  Saying that it's there in response to my comment about it being missing *when you added in response to my criticism* is pretty transparent.

Comment: OK, I've pruned the extensive and heated meta-commentary about votes from here. If you want to continue that discussion, I recommend either taking it to chat or to Meta. Just please be civil if you do so.